# How to get class name directly as a output from yolo tf serving

Tags: tensorflow, deployment, object-detection, tensorflow-serving, yolo

I want to get output from my custom yolov2 as a list of dictionaries of the identified object. Dark flow has a function return_predict() which does the same but while creating tf serving file. I am not able to give my output layer such that I will get similar results.

link to code : https://gist.github.com/sugartom/70b58505bf5f28d1cf5d05904f6c0af2

here tfnet.out - gives a tensor but i want the class predicted.

eg result that i want - [{'label': 'buckle', 'confidence': 0.32669073, 'topleft': {'x': 368, 'y': 364}, 'bottomright': {'x': 420, 'y': 414}}]

github repo : https://github.com/thtrieu/darkflow

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem but could not find a  way yet. However order of prediction tensor is always the same. So by checking at the begining, results could be related to classes. 
For my findings, tf serving does not support classify. Only predict works unless some modifications done to source.

Comment: I have posted the solution https://github.com/thtrieu/darkflow/issues/403